# REST Input for POST: Can same resource differentiate between JSON and XML Input?

Tags: rest

I have requirement where a same resource needs to support multiple data types as input? What is the best way to do it? 
Should I make 2 different resource with explicitly mentioning what the input data type must be? Or is there a way to differentiate between the input object just based on a header like Content-Type?

Another problem is, even if there is a way to do it in a single resource, how do I define my object? As I was thinking of changing the objects for both the formats.

I am using JAVA for development.

Answer (score 0):

> Or is there a way to differentiate between the input object just based on a header like Content-Type?

That is the purpose of the Content-Type request header. Use that.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Quentin you can use the Content-Type to differentiate the input resource. On the jax-rs implementation you can use `@Consumes` and if required `@Produces` annotations to match the requests and handle them appropriately.

If you are having different objects to bind to for the different input formats just use different mappers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I am finding difficult to understand is, even if the path of an API is same, is REST intelligent enough to switch between APIs based on the content-type?

Comment: Great, i am glad it helped. Usually SO users upvote and accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made basic mistake. I started reading from the beginning  regarding resources. (I cannot add the link to the question that clarified my doubts, I guess stackoverflow does not allow 1 to add links in comments).
I really wanted to upvote both the answers, but the site does not allow me to do so. I am new to stackoverflow, and I dont have enough reputation. It only allow users with 15+ repo to upvote.